# Nest.js array dto validation and transformation date to string

Tags: arrays, typescript, datetime, nestjs, dto

When I send a JavaScript Date() object via a put request to my Nest backend I assume that the date format stays like it is. However, it is passed as a string which makes it very complicated to handle. I tried DTOs. The problem here is that the data is nested in an array. Can I apply the DTO to interfaces as well.

This is what I have so far:

**OpeningHoursInterface.ts**

```
export interface OpeningHoursInterface {
    dayOfWeek: number,
    open: Date,
    close: Date,
    isOpen: boolean
}
```

**DTO.ts**

```
import { IsArray, IsObject, IsString, ValidateNested } from "class-validator";
import { CnmInterface } from "../interfaces/cnm.interface";
import { OpeningHoursInterface } from "../interfaces/openingHours.interface";


export class UpdateCnmDto {

    @IsString()
    _id: string;

    @IsObject()
    cnm: CnmInterface;

    @IsArray()
    @ValidateNested({ each: true })
    openingHours: [OpeningHoursInterface]

}
```

**controller.ts**

```
  @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
  @Put('')
  @UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true }))
  async updateCnm(@Body() updateCnmDto: UpdateCnmDto, @GetUser() user: UserInterface) {
    console.log("update cnm in controler", updateCnmDto)
    return await this.storesService.updateCnm(updateCnmDto, user)
  }
```

**UPDATE 2021-03-28:**

Thank you very much for your answer!

I get the following error in my console:

```
error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
```

In VS-Code I get the error ts(2693) it says that the "OpeningHoursInterface" is related to a type but used as a value.

I tried to modify my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true
  }
}
```

Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Send the date in string format preferably in [iso-format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) instead of new Date(). So will easy to parse

Answer (score 4):

Use the `@Type` annotation of `'class-transformer'`. However, you need a class and not an interface in order for it to work. (`class-transformer` needs to be able to instantiate your type).

```
@IsArray()
@ValidateNested({ each: true })
@Type(() => OpeningHours)
openingHours: [OpeningHours]
```

And then again inside `OpeningHours`:

```
@Type(() => Date)
open: Date

@Type(() => Date)
close: Date
```

Comment: I get the following error: "error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected"
(see above for details)

Comment: Do you have the possibility of making `OpeningHoursInterface` a class rather than an interface? class-transformer needs an entity that can be constructed.